# Add utility classes to Bootstrap 5 that select and style the children of an element

Tags: bootstrap-5

I could use guidance on how to add a utility class to Bootstrap 5 that selects and styles the children. The docs do not show how to add a utility class with a pseudo selector. I would like to re-create the space-between utility classes in bootstrap that exist in tailwindcss. In tailwindcss a spacer utility class looks something like this:

```
.space-x-4 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

It adds space between children but not before the first one or after the last one. You can see more about it here in the tailwindcss docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space. Bootstrap does not have these utility classes so I am trying to create them via the instructions to add utility classes provided by bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#add-utilities.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Stuck on the same thing.

Comment: No I did not @SiddharthBhansali. =[

Comment: Might be too late but I think I did manage to find something back then. `.parent_class > * + * { margin-top: 5px; }`. This would add a 5px margin-top to all the children of the `parent_class`.